# How to query WHERE cost > X?

Tags: google-ads-api, google-ads-script

I've run into an issue with the Google Ads Query Validator and need some help debugging.

* API Version: v10

* Query: "SELECT customer.id, metrics.impressions FROM group_placement_view WHERE group_placement_view.placement_type IN ("YOUTUBE_CHANNEL") AND (metrics.impressions + metrics.average_cpm) > 1000000"

* Result: Invalid Query (errors below)

* The filtering condition '(metrics.impressions + metrics.average_cpm) > 1000000' in the WHERE clause is not valid. Filtering conditions must take the form of 'field operator operand'. The operators IS NULL and IS NOT NULL take no operand.

* Link to query result: https://gaql-query-builder.uc.r.appspot.com/v10/share?q=SELECT%20customer.id%2C%20metrics.impressions%20FROM%20group_placement_view%20WHERE%20group_placement_view.placement_type%20IN%20(%22YOUTUBE_CHANNEL%22)%20AND%20(metrics.impressions%20%2B%20metrics.average_cpm)%20%3E%201000000

* Expected result:
Using SQL, I can do arithmetic operation in the "WHERE" clause.
This syntax is not valid for GAQL?

How can I filter group_placements WHERE the spend is above X ?
There is no metric "spend" or "cost"

I thought to use:
(all_conversions * cost_per_all_conversions)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. GAQL isn't SQL. It's up to the developer to do any arithmetic operations on the returned AdsRows.

You can put a simple predicate based operator on the WHERE clause but only for limiting results of that exact resource (like the cost_micros below).

```
SELECT 
campaign.name, 
ad_group.name, customer.id, 
customer.descriptive_name,
campaign.advertising_channel_type,
segments.date,
metrics.cost_micros,
metrics.impressions,
metrics.clicks,
metrics.ctr,
metrics.conversions
FROM ad_group_ad
WHERE segments.date BETWEEN {date_range}
AND campaign.advertising_channel_type = 'SEARCH'
AND metrics.cost_micros > 0
ORDER BY segments.date
```